# Can you configure VSCode's auto-import to use an existing index import vice the original code file when coding in JavaScript/TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, auto-import

In my TypeScript project, I prefer to use an index.ts that can define exports from all my modules in a proper order for the code to work.  Part of such a file looks something like this:

```ts
// from index.ts
export * from "../common/index";
export * from "./DomTools";
export * from "./ClientUserSession";
export * from "./ClientGameSession";
export * from "./LibraryManager";
export * from "./RichTextEditor";
export * from "./Binding";
export * from "./StyleSheetManager";
export * from "./ViewBinder";
...
```

In a given code file, I may have the following:

```ts
// from DummyClass.ts
import {
    GameState,            // Comes from ../common/GameState.ts
    ViewBinder,           // Comes from ./ViewBinder.ts
} from "./index".         // this could also be from "."

export class DummyClass {
    // NOTE: ClientGameSession must be imported...
    public constructor(public readonly gameSession: ClientGameSession){}
}
```

If I simply type this portion of the code: `ClientGameSession)`, VSCode will automatically add this line to the header of the file:

```ts
import { ClientGameSession } from "./ClientGameSession";
```

However, if I reject that (undo) and instead get quick-fix suggestions from VSCode, it will offer to `update import from "./index"`.  Selecting that option puts the import where I want it:

```ts
import {
    GameState,            // Comes from ../common/GameState.ts
    ViewBinder,           // Comes from ./ViewBinder.ts
    ClientGameSession,    // >>> THIS is what I prefer
} from "./index".         // this could also be from "."
```

So the obvious question is:

Can I configure VSCode so that when it automatically adds an import as I type, it uses what is essentially the first suggestion I would get in a quick-fix list (i.e., it would add the import to an existing "./index" import list) rather than adding a new import from the original code file for the item in question?

Thanks!